# Why does compiler report "irrelevant" candidate templates for operator+

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a `widget<T>` class that supports `operator+` with any other `widget<T>`.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct widget {
  widget<T> operator+(const widget<T>&) {
    return {};
  }
};
```

When I add `widget<int>` and `widget<double>`, I get short and simple error as expected:

```
<source>:14:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('widget<int>' and 'widget<double>')
    auto z = x + y;
             ~ ^ ~
<source>:6:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'widget<double>' to 'const widget<int>' for 1st argument
    widget<T> operator+(const widget<T>&) {
              ^
```

However, when I try to add a `widget<int>` and a `widget<std::vector<int>>`, I get a ton of extra errors saying "candidate template ignored..." for a whole bunch of types that (in my opinion) should not have been considered.

```
<source>:14:16: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('widget<int>' and 'widget<std::vector<int>>')
    auto z = x + y;
             ~ ^ ~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:630:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'widget'
    operator+(typename reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type __n,
    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1786:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'widget'
    operator+(typename move_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type __n,
    ^

[... lots more of this ...]

    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.2.0/../../../../include/c++/12.2.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:627:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'basic_string' against 'widget'
    operator+(_CharT __lhs, const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __rhs)
    ^
<source>:6:15: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'widget<std::vector<int>>' to 'const widget<int>' for 1st argument
    widget<T> operator+(const widget<T>&) {
              ^
```

If all these candidates weren't considered when I tried to add `widget<int>` and `widget<double>`, why are they suddenly considered now? Is there anything I can do to get a "friendlier" error message?

I'm seeing this behavior with all 3 compilers: GCC, Clang, and MSVC.

[View on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/G76bo1hnv)

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) finds more candidates from `std` namespace when you mention `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you, the page you linked describes it well. Is there a way for me to modify the code, so that the additional candidates are not considered? Separately, I added an additional overload requiring `!is_same_v<T,U>` and marked it `= delete`. This works for GCC and MSVC, but not clang.

Comment: It's unclear why you'd want to disable them, they don't affect anything other than the error messages in this case.

Comment: @samw I don't thinks so as this is a language feature..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The class is part of a library I am writing. In this question, I kept the example as simple as possible, but my real use case relies on a requires-clause. I wanted to test the friendliness of the error message when the constraint was not met, and was surprised to see all these additional candidates making the error message huge.

Comment: The solution to this is `template <class T> struct foo { struct widget {...}; };`. You can additionally add a templated `using` as a shorthand. If the template parameters come from the enclosing class, they are not considered for ADL.

Comment: The compiler has no idea which `operator+` the user wants, so it lists all candidates it considered. If you know it's your `operator+`, write one that *is* selected even if the user makes an error of the sort you envision, and `static_assert` out the cases you do not want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The candidates are not irrelevant. The candidates are found through argument-dependent lookup (ADL) because one of the template arguments of `widget` is `std::vector`. ADL finds functions within the same namespace as the template arguments. In your case, ADL finds numerous `operator+` overloads in `namespace std`.

They are found, but they aren't viable candidates, so they are included in the error message. Without some modifications to your `widget`, this behavior cannot be changed.

#### Solution A - prevent ADL

You can wrap your `widget` in a helper class template so that the template parameters no longer belong to `widget` directly:

```cpp
template <class T>
struct outer {
    struct widget {
        // possible, but not advised:
        // widget operator+(const widget&) { return {}; }

        // better: (hidden friend)
        friend widget oprator+(const widget&, const widget&) { return {}; }
    };
};

// helper alias template for convenience
template <class T>
using widget = typename outer<T>::widget; // typename is unnecessary since C++20 here
```

With this solution, the template argument `std::vector` would belong to `outer`, not to `widget`, which prevents ADL from finding all those overloads in `namespace std`.

#### Solution B - `static_assert`

Another option is to create an `operator+` which accepts any combinations of widgets and verifies through a `static_assert` whether the combination of types was valid.

```cpp
template <class T>
struct widget {
    // TODO: if necessary, declare the function template as a friend here
};

template <class L, class R>
widget<L> operator+(const widget<L>&, const widget<R>&) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<L, R>, "Adding two widgets requires them to have the same type");
    return {};
}
```

This works, but it isn't SFINAE friendly, i.e. you can't test whether the expression `a + b` is valid for two widgets using a `requires` expression or other means. It's always valid, but the instantiation may result in a compiler error.